# Insert From XML File

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I'm attempting to update a customer table using an XML file, but it's not pulling the values from the XML into the variables to pass into the table. The error I get says "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EmailAddress'" even though there is clearly a value for EmailAddress. I feel like I'm missing something very simple, but can't figure it out. Any thoughts?

```
USE MyGuitarShop

DECLARE @CustomerUpdate XML

SET @CustomerUpdate = 
    '<NewCustomers>
        <Customer EmailAddress="izzychan@yahoo.com" Password="" FirstName="Isabella" LastName="Chan" />
        <Customer EmailAddress="johnprine@gmail.com" Password="" FirstName="John" LastName="Prine" />
        <Customer EmailAddress="kathykitchen@sbcglobal.net" Password="" FirstName="Kathy" LastName="Kitchen" />
    </NewCustomers>';

INSERT Customers (EmailAddress, Password, FirstName, LastName)
    VALUES
    (
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/EmailAddress)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/Password)[1]', 'varchar(60)'),
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(60)'),
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/LastName)[1]', 'varchar(60)')        
    );

SELECT * FROM Customers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I  feel like I'm missing something very simple ...

Yeah, you're right :-D, You are missing the `@` to read the **attribute**-value:

```
DECLARE @CustomerUpdate XML

SET @CustomerUpdate = 
    '<NewCustomers>
        <Customer EmailAddress="izzychan@yahoo.com" Password="" FirstName="Isabella" LastName="Chan" />
        <Customer EmailAddress="johnprine@gmail.com" Password="" FirstName="John" LastName="Prine" />
        <Customer EmailAddress="kathykitchen@sbcglobal.net" Password="" FirstName="Kathy" LastName="Kitchen" />
    </NewCustomers>';

SELECT
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@EmailAddress)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@Password)[1]', 'varchar(60)'),
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(60)'),
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@LastName)[1]', 'varchar(60)')
```

### UPDATE: Insert all `<Customer>` in one go

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Customers TABLE(EMailAddress VARCHAR(100),[Password] VARCHAR(100),FirstName VARCHAR(100),LastName VARCHAR(100));

DECLARE @CustomerUpdate XML

SET @CustomerUpdate = 
    '<NewCustomers>
        <Customer EmailAddress="izzychan@yahoo.com" Password="" FirstName="Isabella" LastName="Chan" />
        <Customer EmailAddress="johnprine@gmail.com" Password="" FirstName="John" LastName="Prine" />
        <Customer EmailAddress="kathykitchen@sbcglobal.net" Password="" FirstName="Kathy" LastName="Kitchen" />
    </NewCustomers>';

INSERT INTO @Customers (EmailAddress, Password, FirstName, LastName)
SELECT c.value('@EmailAddress', 'varchar(255)')
      ,c.value('@Password', 'varchar(60)')
      ,c.value('@FirstName', 'varchar(60)')
      ,c.value('@LastName', 'varchar(60)')        
FROM @CustomerUpdate.nodes(N'/NewCustomers/Customer') AS A(c)

SELECT * FROM @Customers
```

Comment: Fantastic! I completely didn't even realize I needed to have that. Thank you very much for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly now.

```
    USE MyGuitarShop

DECLARE @CustomerUpdate XML

SET @CustomerUpdate = 
    '<NewCustomers>
        <Customer EmailAddress="izzychan@yahoo.com" Password="" FirstName="Isabella" LastName="Chan" />
        <Customer EmailAddress="johnprine@gmail.com" Password="" FirstName="John" LastName="Prine" />
        <Customer EmailAddress="kathykitchen@sbcglobal.net" Password="" FirstName="Kathy" LastName="Kitchen" />
    </NewCustomers>';

INSERT Customers (EmailAddress, Password, FirstName, LastName)
    VALUES
    (
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@EmailAddress)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@Password)[1]', 'varchar(60)'),
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(60)'),
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@LastName)[1]', 'varchar(60)')       
    );

INSERT Customers (EmailAddress, Password, FirstName, LastName)
    VALUES
    (
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@EmailAddress)[2]', 'varchar(255)'),
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@Password)[2]', 'varchar(60)'),
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@FirstName)[2]', 'varchar(60)'),
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@LastName)[2]', 'varchar(60)')       
    );

INSERT Customers (EmailAddress, Password, FirstName, LastName)
    VALUES
    (
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@EmailAddress)[3]', 'varchar(255)'),
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@Password)[3]', 'varchar(60)'),
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@FirstName)[3]', 'varchar(60)'),
        @CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@LastName)[3]', 'varchar(60)')       
    );

SELECT * FROM Customers
```

Comment: Well, this might work *perfectly*, but there's no need to duplicate your code and use a hardcoded position (like `[2]`). Check my updated answer for an approach using `.nodes()` to get a derived table out of your XML.

Comment: That's even better. I'm not advanced enough to know how to do it that way, so I'm glad you showed that to me. It will make this and future code much simpler to do. Thank you.